# one-liner to check if at least one item in list exists in another list?

Tags: python

Lets say I have a list
`a=[1,2,3]`
And I want to know if at least one of the numbers in it exist in another list, like this one:
`b=[4,5,6,7,8,1]`
In other words, I want to know if 1,2 or 3 exist(s) in list `b`.
I now I could do something like

```
def func(a, b):
    for i in a:
       if i in b:
          return True
    return False
```

But is there possibly a way to put that in one line to make things tidy?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. The most direct translation is:

```
any_in = lambda a, b: any(i in b for i in a)
```

You could also use various things involving sets, such as:

```
any_in = lambda a, b: bool(set(a).intersection(b))
```

(which depends on the elements of `a` being hashable, but if that's true, it'll probably be faster to make a set of the larger out of `a` and `b` for either of these approaches).

Edit: `isdisjoint` is better than `intersection` for Python 2.6 and above, as noted by various people below. Glad to learn about that. :)

Answer (score 84):

Python 2.6 and above:

```
def func(a, b):
  return not set(a).isdisjoint(b)
```

For 2.4 or 2.5:

```
def func(a, b):
  return len(set(a).intersection(b)) != 0
```

For 2.3 and below:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

;)

Comment: upvote for 2.3 and below. that was funny :D...correct answer though

Comment: Upvote for the LOLs

Comment: probably time to update the 2.3 advice to `2.6 and below` or even `3.4 and below`

Answer (score 79):

a simple one-liner would be:

```
any(i in b for i in a)
```

Comment: best pythonic solution

Answer (score 19):

This is a *set* problem, not a *list* problem.  With the right data type, the answer is often immediately obvious :-)

```
def func(a, b):
    return not set(a).isdisjoint(b)
```

Comment: @MattO'Brien the OP asks "I want to know if at least one of the numbers in it exist in another list" which logically reduces to a set problem. I'm intrigued by how in your example element a is not in the second list? It seems to be in it, _at least once_. I wonder if you are thinking about the count of elements which would be a `collections.Counter` problem

Comment: good point. I have no idea what I was thinking 2 years ago when I wrote that...I've deleted it...

Comment: what is the right data type ?

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti The "set" datatype is more useful for this problem than a "list".

Answer (score 7):

By converting your lists to sets you can perform set operations on them. If the intersection is larger than 0, you have at least one element matching:

```
len(set(a) & set(b)) > 0
```

Comment: Same idea, other variations:  `bool( set(a) & set(b) )` or simply `set(a) & set(b)`

Comment: not set(a).isdisjoint(set(b))

Answer (score 5):

This should work.

```
def func(a, b):
    return any([i in b for i in a])
```

Comment: what is the output ?

Comment: error : 'Cell' object is not iterable