# Python 2.6: How can I compare two lists of same object types on one particular field, efficiently?

Tags: python, list, loops, foreach, compare

I have a class called "UserDatabaseRecord".  It has a bunch of fields like "username", "expiration_date", and so on.

I have TWO lists of UserDatabaseRecord objects: List A and List B

I want to verify that for all UserDatabaseRecords in List A, the username field does not match any UserDatabaseRecords username field in List B.

I'm able to accomplish this very inefficiently:

```
for record_a in List_A:
   for record_b in List_B:
      if record_a.username == record_b.username:
         print "Duplicate username: {0}".format(record_a.username)
```

It works, I guess.  I'd just like to make it more efficient and/or "Pythonic".

This question is related, but ultimately I couldn't figure out how to apply it to a List of *objects* when comparing on just one field: [one-liner to check if at least one item in list exists in another list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668282/one-liner-to-check-if-at-least-one-item-in-list-exists-in-another-list)

Comment: Is there a reason you made your class `list` backed as opposed to `dict` backed?  If it were keyed by username this operation is instantaneous and one line.

Comment: @roippi Nope, you make a good point.  I had no particular reason other than that I was more familiar and comfortable with Lists at the start of the project.  It's a small project, so no big deal, but definitely something I'll better utilize in my future projects.

Comment: @CptSupermrkt: It still might be worth rearranging your data in this project. After all, if it's a small project, it ought to be an easy change, and a good learning experience, right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem with this is that, for each element in list A, you're checking all of the elements in list B. So, if the lengths of your lists are N and M, that's N*M comparisons.

If you make a set of the usernames from list B, then you can just use the `in` operator on it—which is not only simpler, it's instantaneous, instead of having to check all of the values one by one. So, you only need N lookups instead of N*M.

So:

```
b_names = {record.username for record in List_B}
for record_a in List_A:
    if record_a.username in b_names:
        print "Duplicate username: {0}".format(record_a.username)
```

Or, even simpler, use set intersection:

```
a_names = {record.username for record in List_A}
b_names = {record.username for record in List_B}
for name in a_names & b_names:
    print "Duplicate username: {0}".format(name)
```

And really, you don't need both of them to be sets, you can make one a set and the other just an iterator, using a generator expression:

```
a_names = {record.username for record in List_A}
b_names = (record.username for record in List_B)
for name in a_names.intersection(b_names):
    print "Duplicate username: {0}".format(name)
```

One of these may be a little faster than the others, but they'll all be in the same ballpark—and, more importantly, they're all linear instead of quadratic. So, I'd suggest using whichever one makes the most sense to you.

If you just need to know whether there are duplicates rather than get a list of them, or just need to get one of the duplicates arbitrarily rather than all of them, you can speed it up by "short-circuiting" early—e.g., adding a `break` after the `print` in the first one, or using `isdisjoint` instead of `intersection` in the last one.

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like:

```
for rec_a, rec_b in zip(List_A, List_B):
    if rec_a == rec_b:
        print "Duplicate username: {0}".format(rec_a.username)
```

Comment: This does something totally different; it only checks each element in `List_B` against the corresponding element in `List_A`; he wants to check against _all_ elements in `List_A`.