# How to Find List Membership in a List in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a list that I would like to use to see if any of the members of the list are in a second list, and use that in an Ansible `when` clause. Can this be done in a one-liner?

```
- name: task include moar ansible
  include: more_tasks.yaml
  when: any_member_of_this_list in some_other_list
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is quite easy. Ansible [introduced some extra Jinja filters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html), and one of them is `intersect`, which returns unique elements which are contained in two lists. Since an empty list is falsy and a non-empty list is truthy, there is not more to be done than this:

```
when: any_member_of_this_list | intersect(some_other_list)
```

Comment: I am going to try this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's probably a way to do it in one play with a lot of fancy jinja2 commands, but you may be less likely to go insane by using your own custom plugin. If you create a 'filter_plugins' directory in the root of the folder you keep your ansible scripts, Ansible will automagically find them. Here's my 'filter_plugins/contains_any.py' file:

```
# lambda gratefully 'borrowed' from:
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668282/one-liner-to-check-if-at-least-one-item-in-list-exists-in-another-list
contains_any = lambda a, b: any(i in b for i in a)
class FilterModule(object):

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'contains_any': contains_any
        }
```

In your playbook, you can use the 'set_fact' module to set the the True/False value based on whether there are any matches between the lists. When you pipe 'the_list' into 'contains_any', it automatically sets 'the_list' as the first variable, so you only need to explicitly pass 'the_other_list':

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
   the_list: [jane, bill, janet, suzy]
   the_other_list: [jane, steve, bob, sam, turkey]
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
     any_matches: "{{ the_list | contains_any(the_other_list) }}"
  - debug: msg="Success!"
    when: any_matches
```

Here's the output:

```
PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Success!"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

EDIT: Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668282/one-liner-to-check-if-at-least-one-item-in-list-exists-in-another-list) for the lambda function

Comment: You only need one fancy jinja filter. :) I think your lambda function does exactly what the `intersect ` filter does. See my other answer.

Comment: This is a big hammer, but now I know how to do it for even more complicated stuff. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Randy Hah! Yeah, definitely a big hammer, particularly given udondan's one-liner, but it's definitely good to know that building custom filters is quite easy.