# Search a python list for matches to a custom list of stem words of varying length

Tags: python, list, nlp, tokenize

I'm trying to search word-tokenized abstracts for custom stem words using python. The following code is almost what I want. That is, do any of the values in stem_words appears once or more in word_tokenized_abstract?

```
if(any(word in stem_words for word in word_tokenized_abstract)):
    do stuff
```

where...

- stem_words is a list of strings only
- word_tokenized_abstract is a list of strings only

I based the above at [one-liner to check if at least one item in list exists in another list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668282/one-liner-to-check-if-at-least-one-item-in-list-exists-in-another-list)

My issue is that my stem_words are of different lengths. I've tried the following code (a modification of the above) which did not work for me. I've tried a few other modifications but they either don't work or cause a crash.

```
if(any(word in stem_words for word[0:len(word)] in word_tokenized_abstract)):
    do stuff
```

That is, do any of the values word_tokenized_abstract begin with any of the values in `stem_words`?

if it helps, my `stem_words = ['pancrea', 'muscul', 'derma', 'ovar']`

Thanks! I apologize if this question has been answered previously but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to check if any string in a first list is contained in any of the strings of the second list.

I'd try this:

```
any(y.startswith(x) for y in word_tokenized_abstract for x in stem_words)
```

Explanation: for each stem `x` in `stem_words` check if any string in `word_tokenized_abstract` starts with `x`.

If you just want the stem to be a substring of the word then use:

```
any(x in y for y in word_tokenized_abstract for x in stem_words)
```

Comment: Thanks user2314737! That is exactly what I needed (including the startswith method). And thanks for replying so quickly.