# Check if two Python sets have at least one common element

Tags: python, algorithm, set

What is the fastest way to check if two sets in Python have at least one common element? The desired output is a True/False.

e.g. I tried with set.intersection(), but I would like to avoid checking all the elements in both sets.

```
set.intersection({1,2,3}, {8,9,2})
>>> {2}
```

NOTE: I'm searching for a very efficient solution that works with Python sets (I'm not asking about lists)

Comment: Do you want to return `true` as **if two sets have at least one common element** or do you want to return `2`?

Comment: How about `not`[`isdisjoint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.isdisjoint)?

Comment: I want to return True. Thank for the note, I edited the question.

Comment: Found a dup. So does this answer your question? [one-liner to check if at least one item in list exists in another list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668282/one-liner-to-check-if-at-least-one-item-in-list-exists-in-another-list)

Comment: Lists are definitively different from sets! I searching for a very efficient solution with sets

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`{1,2,3}.isdisjoint({4,5,6})`
will return true since there is no intersection.

Answer (score 1):

```
def intersect(a, b):
    if len(a) > len(b):
        a, b = b, a   
    for c in a:
        if c in b:
            return c
```

The above code is similar to the implementation of `intersection( )`, except that this version returns the first element that is matched. You could also return true if required, instead of the first matched element.